# PHP OOP returning and calling single array value

Tags: php, oop

I'm in the process of learning to use OOP in php, I'm having a few issues with what is probably a really simple solution that I'm just not using the right search terminology to find.

I have my class

```
class user {

    function getUser() {

        if ($_SESSION['status'] == "authorized") {

            $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

            $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );

            $st->bindValue( ":username", $_SESSION['usernames'], PDO::PARAM_STR );

            $st->execute();

            $row = $st->fetch();

            $conn = null;

            return $row;

        }
    }
}
```

and then in my template file i'm calling the following

```
$user = new user();
echo $user->getUser->icon;
```

hopefully the bottom line shows what i'm trying to call, basically in the sql results I'm after just calling $row['icon']; directly from the return array.

is this possible? if so could someone point out the terminology i'm missing

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should start your class with an upper case letter, in this case: `User`

Comment: Note that PHP/5.4.0 and later support array dereferencing, so `echo $user->getUser()['icon'];` is now valid syntax and will do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to keep using that object I would do the following:

```
class user {
    public $icon;

    function getUser() {

    if ($_SESSION['status'] == "authorized") {

        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

        $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );

        $st->bindValue( ":username", $_SESSION['usernames'], PDO::PARAM_STR );

        $st->execute();

        $row = $st->fetch();

        $conn = null;

        $this->icon=$row;

    }
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
echo $user->icon;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
print_r ($user->getUser);
```

If that returns an array, try it like this :

```
echo $user->getUser['icon'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it this way:

```
$userobj = new User();
$user = $userobj->getUser();
```

Now you have the fetched data in the `$user` variable and may output it at will:

```
echo $user['icon'];
```

My example should work with your existing code, and if you want to change the values in the future of the users, you just change the key in the echo statement: echo `$user['someothervalue'];`